# Correct classpath of ur app so that it contain a single compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting the below error
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.startup.StartupEndpointAutoConfiguration$ApplicationStartupCondition.getMatchOutcome(StartupEndpointAutoConfiguration.java:63)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.getApplicationStartup()Lorg/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup;
```

The method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, is available from the following locations:
jar:file:/Users/doc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.class

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/Users/doc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory

POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>

</parent>



<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 

   
    <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
    <spring-retry.version>1.3.1</spring-retry.version>
    <spring-cloud-netflix-core.version>1.1.7.RELEASE</spring-cloud-netflix-core.version>
    <spring-cloud-vault-config.version>3.1.1</spring-cloud-vault-config.version>
    <spring-vault-core.version>2.3.2</spring-vault-core.version>
 



    <!-- Swagger Dependencies -->
    <springfox-swagger2.version>2.4.0</springfox-swagger2.version>

   
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-retry.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-netflix-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-vault-config.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-vault-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.SR6</version>
        </dependency>
       
        
       
        <!-- Swagger Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-staticdocs</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-vault-config.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-vault-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
   
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: In short your dependencies are a mess. You are mixing all sorts of incompatible versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. You already have the spring cloud dependencies in dependency management (scope should be import and type should be pom). So remove the version of the Spring Cloud dependencies, ditch the `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure` that is already pulled in through `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. There is probably more wrong with it but that is a start.

Comment: When i removed spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:335)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration

Comment: Which is because youa re mixing a whole slew of incompatible versions. Remove all the `version` tags in your `dependencies` section. Remove `spring-retry` from dependency management. Aso remove the overrides for Spring Vault etc. those are all managed by the `spring-cloud-dependencies` one.

Comment: i am getting like this
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource

Comment: As stated before you are mixing a slew of incompatible versions, simplify your dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to outsmart the Spring Boot and Spring Cloud dependency management and are including a slew of incompatible versions. Simplify your dependency management by only adding `spring-cloud-dependencies` in your `dependencyManagement` section. Remove all the other as those are already managed by either Spring Boot or the Spring Cloud dependencies you have.

Next remove the versions from the dependencies in your `dependencie` section and remove the `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfiguration` dependency, that is included in the `spring-boot-starter`.

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <!-- Swagger Dependencies -->
    <springfox-swagger2.version>2.4.0</springfox-swagger2.version>

   
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.SR12</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-staticdocs</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud Starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   
</dependencies>
```

Now the dependencies are properly managed by Spring Boot and Spring Cloud in versions that are compatible.

Comment: I Tried this solution , now i am getting an error like this
Description:
The bean 'clientAuthentication', defined in class path resource [User/content/solution/starter/vault/VaultPrimerAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
Action:
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true  @M.Deinum

Comment: Why did you redifine the auto configuratio nin the first place? Remove the custom one and use the original one.

Comment: I have used the same Dependencies you have provided above. and i could resolve the conflicting issue. But now facing bean not overriding issue - @M.deninum

Comment: I Tried adding "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true" in application.properties .But it isn't working

Comment: Have you read my comment? Why do you even have that configuration class. That is one of your own classes that interferes with a spring one due to it having the same name. Looks like you have conflicting auto-configuration, as stated remove that class.